# Is Time travel associated with the snapshot?

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm a bit confused with the time travel option in BigQuery.

I need point in time recovery for a month.

Is time-travel associated with the snapshot and hence if I snapshot a month ago (say 1/9) can I recover from 1/9 to 7/9 using time travel or is time travel always only the last 7 days (e.g. today is 11th so 4th to 11th is all time travel will give me?)?

Thanks

Comment: Hi @Person of earth, Can you check this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/time-travel#time_travel) ? Hope this helps you resolving the issue.

Comment: Thanks, I've read that document, from that I would take it, it is 7 days from today but if this is the case seems its just not possible to recover over 7 days even with snapshot.

Comment: Hi @Person of earth, As per the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/table-snapshots-intro#table_snapshots), With table snapshots, you can preserve a table's data from a specified point in time for as long as you want. BigQuery provides a [Fail-Safe](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/time-travel#fail-safe) period where you can recover the deleted data for an additional seven days. Let me know if this helps you ?